# Any way to automate SFSafariViewController in UI tests?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, coded-ui-tests, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

Is there any way to automate SFSafariViewController? I like the Xcode 7 UI test feature, but it seems it does not support SFSafariViewController automation. Some of the UI flows I am testing require a web browser so the app uses SFSafariViewController to make it safer vs a web view.

Comment: I'm also very interested in this. Have you found some kind of way around this?

Comment: @Martin Unfortunately nothing at this time.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to automate exactly.

Comment: In my case I want to automate a login flow into a third-party service with a test account.

Answer (score 2):

If it's similar to launching extensions (currently broken with direct interactions), try tapping the screen at the point where the element you're looking for is:

Example of tapping an action sheet which launches an extension:

```
func tapElementInActionSheetByPosition(element: XCUIElement!) {
    let tableSize = app.tables.elementBoundByIndex(0).frame.size
    let elementFrame = element.frame

    // get the frame of the cancel button, because it has a real origin point
    let CancelY = app.buttons["Cancel"].frame.origin.y

    // 8 is the standard apple margin between views
    let yCoordinate = CancelY - 8.0 - tableSize.height + elementFrame.midY

    // tap the button at its screen position since tapping a button in the extension picker directly is currently broken
    app.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVectorMake(elementFrame.midX / tableSize.width, yCoordinate / app.frame.size.height)).tap()
}
```

Note: You must tap at the XCUIApplication query layer. Tapping the element by position doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For now Xcode 9.3 has support for that, but it doesn't work properly because of [annoying Xcode bug](http://www.openradar.me/36788196).

In test you can print  `app.webViews.buttons.debugDescription` or `app.webViews.textFields.debugDescription`, and it prints correct information, but after `tap` or `typeText` you have crash.

To workaround you can parse `debugDescription`, extract coordinates and tap by coordinate. For text field you can insert text via "Paste" menu.

```
private func coordinate(forWebViewElement element: XCUIElement) -> XCUICoordinate? {
    // parse description to find its frame
    let descr = element.firstMatch.debugDescription
    guard let rangeOpen = descr.range(of: "{{", options: [.backwards]),
        let rangeClose = descr.range(of: "}}", options: [.backwards]) else {
            return nil
    }

    let frameStr = String(descr[rangeOpen.lowerBound..<rangeClose.upperBound])
    let rect = CGRectFromString(frameStr)

    // get the center of rect
    let center = CGVector(dx: rect.midX, dy: rect.midY)
    let coordinate = XCUIApplication().coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: .zero).withOffset(center)
    return coordinate
}

func tap(onWebViewElement element: XCUIElement) {
    // xcode has bug, so we cannot directly access webViews XCUIElements
    // as workaround we can check debugDesciption, find frame and tap by coordinate
    let coord = coordinate(forWebViewElement: element)
    coord?.tap()
}
```

Article about that: https://medium.com/@pilot34/work-with-sfsafariviewcontroller-or-wkwebview-in-xcode-ui-tests-8b14fd281a1f

Full code is here: https://gist.github.com/pilot34/09d692f74d4052670f3bae77dd745889