# How to write UI tests covering login with Facebook in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I would like to write a UI test in Xcode covering a login with [`FBDSKLoginKit`](https://cocoapods.org/pods/FBSDKLoginKit).

However, [Facebook iOS SDK uses `SFSafariViewController`](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/10/29/Facebook-Login-iOS9/) presented to the user in order to authenticate her and unfortunately, [there's no way how to interact with `SFSafariViewController` in UI tests in Xcode 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32763010/any-way-to-automate-sfsafariviewcontroller-in-ui-tests).

*Any ideas how to test the facebook login without interacting with `SFSafariViewController`?*

Comment: You can take a look at my notes https://github.com/onmyway133/blog/issues/44

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3 Xcode 8 solution**

```
 func testFacebookLogin() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()

    // set up an expectation predicate to test whether elements exist
    let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")

    // as soon as your sign in button shows up, press it
    let facebookSignInButton = app.buttons["Login With Facebook"]
    expectation(for: exists, evaluatedWith: facebookSignInButton, handler: nil)
    facebookSignInButton.tap()

    // wait for the "Confirm" title at the top of facebook's sign in screen
    let confirmTitle = app.staticTexts["Confirm"]
    expectation(for: exists, evaluatedWith: confirmTitle, handler: nil)

    // create a reference to the button through the webView and press it
    let webView = app.descendants(matching: .webView)
    webView.buttons["OK"].tap()

    // wait for your app to return and test for expected behavior here
    self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 10, handler: nil)        
}
```

**Extension:**

```
extension XCUIElement {
    func forceTap() {
        if self.isHittable {
            self.tap()
        } else {
            let coordinate: XCUICoordinate = self.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: .zero)
            coordinate.tap()
        }
    }
}
```

Tested and verified to work great!

Comment: For me it didn't work until I added `self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 10.0)` after each expectation line. It's not enough to create an expectation, you have to wait for it...

Comment: You are correct. I have added the required line to my code example. Just tested as well, all is working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3 Xcode 8 update**

```
func testFacebookLogin() {
  let app = XCUIApplication()

  // set up an expectation predicate to test whether elements exist
  let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")

  // as soon as your sign in button shows up, press it
  let facebookSignInButton = app.buttons["Login With Facebook"]
  expectation(for: exists, evaluatedWith: facebookSignInButton, handler: nil)
  facebookSignInButton.tap()

  // wait for the "Confirm" title at the top of facebook's sign in screen
  let confirmTitle = app.staticTexts["Confirm"]
  expectation(for: exists, evaluatedWith: confirmTitle, handler: nil)

  // create a reference to the button through the webView and press it
  let webView = app.descendants(matching: .webView)
  webView.buttons["OK"].tap()

  // wait for your app to return and test for expected behavior here
  self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 10, handler: nil)        
}
```

Extension:

```
extension XCUIElement {
  func forceTap() {
      if self.isHittable {
          self.tap()
      } else {
          let coordinate: XCUICoordinate = self.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: .zero)
          coordinate.tap()
      }
  }
```

**Swift 2**

```
func testFacebookLogin() 
{
    let app = XCUIApplication()

    // set up an expectation predicate to test whether elements exist
    let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")

    // as soon as your sign in button shows up, press it
    let facebookSignInButton = app.buttons["Sign in with Facebook"]
    expectationForPredicate(exists, evaluatedWithObject: facebookSignInButton, handler: nil)
    facebookSignInButton.tap()

    // wait for the "Confirm" title at the top of facebook's sign in screen
    let confirmTitle = app.staticTexts["Confirm"]
    expectationForPredicate(exists, evaluatedWithObject: confirmTitle, handler: nil)

    // create a reference to the button through the webView and press it
    var webView = app.descendantsMatchingType(.WebView)
    webView.buttons["OK"].tap()

    // wait for your app to return and test for expected behavior here
}
```

In my case, I also had to deal with the *Assertion Failure: UI Testing Failure - Unable to find hit point for Button* error via the forceTap() extension:

```
extension XCUIElement {
    func forceTap() {
        if self.hittable {
            self.tap()
        } else {
            let coordinate: XCUICoordinate = self.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVectorMake(0.0, 0.0))
            coordinate.tap()
        }
    }
}
```

as per this awesome blog post [here](http://samwize.com/2016/02/28/everything-about-xcode-ui-testing-snapshot/)